# Deserializing objects and adding it to an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, deserialization

Now I am creating an address book in Java 1.6.  Now how I have it set up is when you add a contact it gets saved into an array.  I have no problem writing the array, however when it comes to reading it I dont know how to get every object I previously saved, and load it into the array again.

Just do you know:  addbook is my file, it is a txt file.  Array is the array I am using to store the objects.  The sort I am using is an insertion sort that sorts the contacts by name.  If I have not covered other variable names, and stuff like that, I can clarify.

Finally, just for clarification, my question is asking how I can read the array I saved to a file.
Here is my read code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(addBook);
    ObjectInputStream readIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);

    array = readIn.readObject();
    readIn.close();


    Sorts.insertionSort(array);

    model.removeAllElements();

    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        model.addElement(((Book) array[i]).getContact());
    }
    comboBox.setModel(model);

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? What isn't working? Never just swallow `Exception` like that without at least putting `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block.

Comment: @Jeffery  This is a summative for my programming class.  What isn't working is this line:  "test =  readIn.readObject();"  The error I get is "Multiple markers as this line"

Comment: What is the type of `array`? `Object`, `Object[]` or `Book[]`?

Comment: @Jeffrey  It is a comparable array.  This is the declaraction I am using:  "Comparable[] array = new Comparable[arraySize];"  arraySize is an integer that counts up as I add a contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ObjectInputStream.readObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) returns an `Object`. You cannot assign an `Object` to a `Comparable[]` without a [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html): `array = (Comparable[]) readIn.readObject()`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeffrey, I really appreciate it. :)  I will accept the answer as answered once the remaining 4 minutes it up.

Comment: @Spartan You are most welcome. I also added a link to the Java tutorial that deals with casting, if you want to take a look at it.